# Error Call to a member function getAttribute() on null

Tags: php, yii2

Error
Call to a member function getAttribute() on null

```
 /**
     * Checks the ability to use fractional seconds.
     *
     * @return bool
     * @see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html
     */
    private function supportsFractionalSeconds()
    {
        $version = $this->db->getSlavePdo()->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION);
        return version_compare($version, '5.6.4', '>=');
```

Comment: I don't know php well, but where is the closing bracket? And what is the error?

Comment: getSlavePdo() is not returning a connection, did you configured the database correctly?